# Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. in 4.0 Site with 2.0 sub folder?

Tags: iis, .net-4.0

I have recently upgraded a site to .net 4.0. I changed the app pool and almost everything is working properly.

However the admin section of the site which is in an 'admin' subfolder with its own web.config is still running under 2.0 for some reason. When I left click the sub directory in IIS and check the ASP.net tab of properties it get ASP.NET version 2.0.50727.

If i click 'Edit Configuration' I get this error
"An error has occured attemping to read the configuration." The error message is:

Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note the attribute names are case-sensitive.

The web config in the protected directly looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- 
    Note: As an alternative to hand editing this file you can use the 
    web admin tool to configure settings for your application. Use
    the Website->Asp.Net Configuration option in Visual Studio.
    A full list of settings and comments can be found in 
    machine.config.comments usually located in 
    \Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.x\Config 
-->
<configuration>
    <appSettings/>
    <connectionStrings/>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>
        </authorization>
        <customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

When I try to navigate to the admin section i get "Server Application Unavailable" and an entry in the app log complaining about two different versions.

Everything is running under the same app pool which is 4.0. Why is the sub folder not 4.0 and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What version of IIS are you running?

My guess, is that at some point, you (or somebody else) manually set the ASP.NET version to 2.0 on the subfolder.

The way it works...  IIS checks to see if the value is not set.  If it is not set, it inherits the value from the parent.   Once the value is set explicitly changing the value at the parent does not cascade to the child.

Comment: I'm running ISS 6. How do you manually set a version on a sub folder? The box is grayed out so I can't change it.

Comment: To truly fix it,  I'd suggest pointing something like Meta-edit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301386 at your IIS instance to see the true cause of the problem.  A possible hack would be to make the admin subdirectory to an application.  This should allow you to change it.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're using IIS6 in which case you'll have to right-click on your sub-directory and change the ASP.Net version.

Comment: I want it to inherit. I want the sub folder to be 4.0. I don't understand why it is 2.0?

Comment: That section is not valid for a 2.0 deployment. You need to either upgrade the 2.0 application to work with 4.0 and change the application pool to use 4.0 or restrict the sections that are invalid for 2.0 applications.

Comment: Rereading the question I see what you're saying now...one moment.

Comment: Yeah. I did upgrade the app. It works great. Even when I run under another IIS website. But there is something specific about this site causing the subfolder to think it is supposed to run under 2.0

Answer (score 0):

For some reason there was an entry for the admin folder in the IIS 6 Metabase. Using the IIS 6 Metabase explorer I was able to delete the ScriptMaps entry that had the data pointing to the 2.0 asapi .dlls.

This fixed my problem.