# SocialAuth.NET is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, socialauth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [unrecognized attribute ‘targetframework’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082517/unrecognized-attribute-targetframework)

I'm trying to use SocialAuth.NET for extract contacts from gmail and yahoo for my web application but when I run the WebformDemo the following error occurs

> Server Error in '/Demo' Application.
>
> Configuration Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a
>   configuration file required to service this request. Please review the
>   specific error details below and modify your configuration file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note
>   that attribute names are case-sensitive.
>
> ```
> Source Error: 
> Line 76:     </authentication>-->
> Line 77:     <!--<authentication mode="None"/>-->
> Line 78:     <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
> Line 79:       <assemblies>
> Line 80:         <add assembly="Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
> ```

```
Source File: D:\test\SocialAuth-net-2.3\WebFormsDemo\web.config   
Line: 78 

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3053;
ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3053
```

I'm using Windows XP and Visual Studio 2010.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry guys I realized my mistake.The problem is I didnt change the asp.net version in IIS..If any one suffer with the same problem go through the following steps

step 1. run-> inetmgr
step 2.create a virtual folder for your directory (http://code.google.com/p/socialauth-net/wiki/Quickstart_Guide)
step 3. right click on your virtual directory then click properties and select asp.net tab and change version to 4.0